# Guaranteeing ACID properties for InnoDB databases

Tags: mysql, innodb, database, data-consistency

What steps must one take to ensure that an otherwise defaultly-configured InnoDB server is truly ACID compliant?  The [InnoDB configuration page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-configuration.html) mentions that the hardware itself must be configured to honor `fsync` calls, i.e. disable any write-back caches.

[This page](http://drbrain.livejournal.com/61705.html) mentions some other concerns, but may be conflating the binary log and the InnoDB log, and may be a bit out of date regarding default settings for MySQL 5.x.

Upon reading [the binary log document page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html) it would seem that the "sync_binlog=1" setting is not required for ACID properties in general, only for ACID properties vis a vis point-in-time recovery and replication.

So, is disabling write-back disk caching sufficient, or are there other settings that must be tweaked?

Answer (score 2):

You ask a hard question.  Here are the settings in MySQL:

- sync-frm
- sync-binlog
- innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1 (default)
- innodb_support_xa = 1 (default)
- innodb_doublewrite= 1 (default)
- sync-relay-log = 1 (if a slave)
- rpl_transaction_enabled=1 (if a slave - only in 5.5 / Percona Server)

And from the OS/Filesystem/etc:

- Disable any non battery backed caches on disks or raid controllers.
- Make sure the OS is not in any laptop mode, etc.

Comment: This information is out of date for MySQL 5.6.  I've written a blog post about it here: http://www.tocker.ca/2013/06/19/deciding-whether-or-not-to-make-mysql-durable.html

Answer (score 1):

Disabling write-back isn't necessarily going to break ACID. It won't do so if you have battery-backed write cache on your RAID controller, and the payoff for having that is a huge increase in write capacity. Something to beware of though is that some hard drives and SSDs (e.g. intel X-25) have their own write back caches that are NOT battery backed even if your RAID controller is and they definitely need disabling. Setting O_DIRECT will also keep your OS and file system out of the way and let the RAID controller do its thing more effectively.

I normally use these settings for reasonable reliability:

```
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_support_xa = 1
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit  = 2
```

Comment: Good point about battery-backed write caches.  I should have said "disable any non-durable write back caches".